# Large MSE and MAE in Linear Regression model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I use [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMtDF.png) to calculate weights and bias.
This is my code:

```
def train(train_X, train_Y):
  X1 = np.insert(train_X, 1, 1, axis=1) # (50, 2)
  weight, bias = np.linalg.inv((X1.T).dot(X1)).dot((X1.T).dot(train_Y))
  return np.array([weight]), bias

Y_train_predicted = X_train.dot(w) + b
Y_test_predicted = X_test.dot(w) + b
```

And use MSE and MAE method to check predicted values:

```
def mse(true, pred):    
    return np.mean((true - pred)**2)

def mae(true, pred):    
    return np.mean(np.abs(true - pred))
```

But my MSE value is over 100, meanwhile I read that in a good model it should strive to 1. And MAE value is over 1 which is also bad. However, the plot shows that predicted values are close to actual:

[image]

My training and test data:

```
def generate_data(n_points=20):
  X = np.linspace(-5, 5, n_points)
  y = 10 * X - 7

  X_train = X[0::2].reshape(-1, 1)
  y_train = y[0::2] + np.random.randn(int(n_points/2)) * 10

  X_test = X[1::2].reshape(-1, 1)
  y_test = y[1::2] + np.random.randn(int(n_points/2)) * 10

  print(f'Generated {len(X_train)} train samples and {len(X_test)} test samples')
  return X, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test
```

How do MSE and MAE methods work? What did I do wrong? Why MSE value is not between 0 and 1?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Did you normalize the input data? Note that you can make MAE as large or small as you want by multiplying all variables with a constant.

Comment: @mcsoini no, I didn't normalize , so every time before learning model we should normalize training data?

Comment: Not necessarily, unless it gets more complex, like in neural nets. However, your rule of thumb "in a good model it should strive to 1" becomes meaningless if the values of the predictions (and hence the error) is arbitrarily scaled.  Besides, are you sure you want the MSE/MAE and not the R2/nMAE? because for those the rules of thumb would make more sense indeed.

Comment: Hi. I run your code and find out that the `w` and  `b` are '9.5' and '-7.8' which are close to the real value. Now consider if your input is `100`, the real value and the predicted value is  '51.8'. It is true for all of your test samples. Therefore, I think the MSE and MAE are greater that 1, are ok.